# Tkinter - Returning from a class and calling a new one

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, tkinter

I was trying to create my own version of the game Go Fish (two players for now) in python 3.4. My game has two main stages. The first one is to determine who is going to make the first move. This is done by calling my class FirstStage (file2.py) which is basically the hand game Rock Paper Scissors - me against robot. After we have a winner, FirstStage returns an integer (0 or 1) which represents the winner of this stage. Then SecondStage class (file3.py) is called passing self.winner as an argument. The game script was split in many files because I use many classes. This is the basic idea but for some reason FistStage is not returning anything. Can some help me with this? Here my code:

file1.py

```
from file2 import *
from file3 import *
import tkinter as tk

class start_gui(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent, *args, **kwargs)
        # create canvas
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(parent, width=800, height=800, background="green")
        self.canvas.pack()

        # here we call FirstStage class to determine who starts first
        self.c = FirstStage(parent)
        self.winner = self.c.getwinner()
        #here we call SecondStage call to start the real game
        self.d = SecondStage(self.winner)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # create main window
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("800x800")
    start_gui(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

file2.py

```
import tkinter as tk
from functools import partial
from PIL import ImageTk
from PIL import Image

class FirstStage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, canv):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, background="black", padx=10, pady=10)
        self.winner = 0
        #here new frame is created
        #buttons and images are place in a grid
        self.rock_paper_scissors()

    def rock_papper_scissors(self):
        #here goes some code 
        #player against API 
        #undefine number of times until there is a winner


    def close(self, w):
        self.grid_forget()
        self.destroy()
        # here buttons, images and frame are destroy
        # save winner
        self.winner = w

    def getwinner(self):
        #return int - 0 for player and 1 for robot(opponent)
        return self.winner
```

file3.py

```
class SecondStage:
    def __init__(self, winner)
        #here goes some scripts
```

Comment: "The game script was split in many files because I use many classes."  Huh?  Python is not Java, there is absolutely no problem with putting multiple classes in a file.

Answer (score 0):

This is long so I couldn't provide it as a comment.

I tested your code as it is (with minor changes) and `FirstStage` returned the correct winner, which at the moment is `0` or whatever value you give in `self.winner = 0`.

1. In *file2.py*, you have `canv` in the `__init__` method but passed
   `parent` to `tk.Frame.__init__`. It gave me error since these
   arguments do not match, hence I changed `canv` to `parent`.
2. The spelling of `rock_paper_scissors` during method definition and
   method call in the `__init__` method are different, check the
   spellings.
3. You tried to change `self.winner` in the `close` method of *file2.py*, but that method is not called anywhere in the code you provided, so `self.winner` stays the same (having a value of `0`).
4. If you put a `print` statement after `self.winner = self.c.getwinner()` in *file1.py*, you'll realize the winner is
   indeed returned.

If you make these changes and still don't get the correct winner, then the problem might be how you implemeted `FirstStage` in `file2.py`; which is not provided in the question.

Here is the code I used for testing:

*file1.py*

```
from file2 import *
from file3 import *
import tkinter as tk

class start_gui(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent, *args, **kwargs)
        # create canvas
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(parent, width=800, height=800, background="green")
        self.canvas.pack()

        # here we call FirstStage class to determine who starts first
        self.c = FirstStage(parent)
        self.winner = self.c.getwinner()
        print(self.winner)
        #here we call SecondStage call to start the real game
        self.d = SecondStage(self.winner)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # create main window
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("800x800")
    start_gui(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

*file2.py*

```
import tkinter as tk
from functools import partial
from PIL import ImageTk
from PIL import Image

class FirstStage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, background="black", padx=10, pady=10)
        self.winner = 0
        #here new frame is created
        #buttons and images are place in a grid
        self.rock_paper_scissors()

    def rock_paper_scissors(self):
        pass
        #here goes some code 
        #player against API 
        #undefine number of times until there is a winner


    def close(self, w):
        self.grid_forget()
        self.destroy()
        # here buttons, images and frame are destroy
        # save winner
        self.winner = w

    def getwinner(self):
        #return int - 0 for player and 1 for robot(opponent)
        return self.winner
```

*file3.py*

```
class SecondStage:
    def __init__(self, winner):
        pass
        #here goes some scripts
```

Comment: Sorry, there was a misspelling on the function rock_paper_scissors on the question I posted but not in my original script. Also, self.winner is changed somewhere in FirstStage class but I did not write it in my post since my script has hundred of lines.

Comment: Basically, FirstStage class enters let's say into a loop until we find a winner.